# Convert to Integer and back to String after calculations

Tags: php, arrays, string, integer

I have an array as follows, which I have put into an array called $testcoords

```
array (
  0 => '\'263',
  1 => '252',)
```

I want to extract the numeric values and manipulate them, then put them back into strings. I am trying to use the following code:

```
$tc2 = explode(":",$testcoords);
$tcx = (int)(trim($tc2[0],"'\'");
$tcy = (int)(trim($tc2[1],"'");
$tcx2 = (($tcx)*(600/386));
$tcy2 = (($tcy)*(600/386));
$xtrans = (string)$tcx2;
$ytrans = (string)$tcy2;
```

So far, I know that the trim functions work - just the (trim($tc2[0],"'\'") or (trim($tc2[1],"'") return me numeric values in two strings.

Now what I'd like to do is take those numeric values, convert to integer which I have tried to combine with the trim functions. Once they are integers, I would like to transfer back into strings and post the results.

When I try to do this, I get no result. Uptil the step of trimming the data is fine.

For example if I just do

```
$tcx = (trim($tc2[0],"'\'");
$tcy = (trim($tc2[1],"'");
```

For the array listed above, and echo the results back, I get 263 and 252 in my response.

Appreciate any pointers on how to complete the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a syntax error. You didn't recognized this because you have disabled error reporting. You can do it using the php.ini setting `display_errors=1` or `log_errors=1` together with a setting like `error_reporting=E_ALL`. You do this also in the script by issuing the following commands:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // for development 
ini_set('display_errors', 0); // for production (display_errors would be a security risk)
ini_set('log_errors', 1); // for both development and production
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

---

The error: You have been missing the closing parenthesis when converting to int. `)`

Use this:

```
$tcx = (int)(trim($tc2[0],"'\'")); // <-- note the second closing ')'
$tcy = (int)(trim($tc2[1],"'"));
```

Further note that this can be simplified by

```
$tcx = (int)(trim($tc2[0],"'\'"); // <-- note the second closing ')'
$tcy = (int)(trim($tc2[1],"'");
```

Comment: thanks. I'm using Bluefish to write the code and one quirk is that it doesn't highlight mismatches, for some reason.

Comment: Read my update. You should enable `display_errors` or `log_errors` instead of rely on the syntax highlighting of your code editor.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary and unclosed parenthesis on these lines before `trim`

```
$tcx = (int)(trim($tc2[0],"'\'");
$tcy = (int)(trim($tc2[1],"'");
```

Change these to:

```
$tcx = (int)trim($tc2[0],"'\'");
$tcy = (int)trim($tc2[1],"'");
```

Also, turn on error_reporting when for developing, you will see such errors noted clearly.